# How to programatically detect if an app supports Android Wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

Im trying to detect if an app supports Android Wear or is a watch face.

```
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();

        List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++)
        {}
```

Is the code im using. Any feedback or suggestions would be awsome!

Answer (score 0):

To check if Android Wear package exists on system:

```
public void foobar() {
    boolean doesExist = isPackageInstalled("com.google.android.wearable.app");
}

private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename) {
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        //swallow exception
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! However, Im trying to see if each individual app itself has a wear component or is a watch face, could I do something with     <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"
        android:required="false" /> ?