# Detect if app is made for Android Wear programmatically

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-hardware, android-wear-notification

I want to detect all apps having Android Wear support. How to detect whether the installed app on device is for Android Wear or not. AFAIK, there aren't any flags in [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) or [ApplicationInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html) that indicates that app supports Android Wear.

There is only one unaccepted [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986474/how-to-programatically-detect-if-an-app-supports-android-wear), which isn't solution of my problem. Can we extract some data from `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"/>` to detect for wearable support. I searched a lot on SO and Google but nothing found even in official docs. Can anyone just help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve this information by inspecting the Android manifest of the package.

Check out the information about packaging of Android Wear apps: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html

Specifically, you want to request the meta data of the app using `PackageManager` (`PackageManager.GET_META_DATA`) and then check the meta data for this field:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.beta.app"
                 android:resource="@xml/wearable_app_desc"/>
```

Comment: ok, I'll try this thanks. It would be nice if framework introduce some flags like FLAG_SUPPORTS_WEARABLE in ApplicationInfo.

Comment: How would you support other vendors that might have their own wearable apps (e.g. Samsung's watches, Pebble)? Android framework shouldn't be aware of vendor's (and Google is treated as a vendor) sub-products.

Comment: ya Its a kind of fragmented world and its terrible. For example, in addition to Android Wear Companion app, I have to install Asus app for asus watch and samsung app for samsung watch; which makes its even more terrible for both users and developers. I would be happy if it would all become centralized under companion app but the wear companion app itself very much buggy and crashes a lot times.