# How to detect android wear 1.0 and 2.0

Tags: android, wear-os, android-productflavors, android-wear-2.0

i have successfully made a project apk which allow the watch download the wear app. And i am trying to use that wearable code to support standalone for wear 2.0 as well - seem not much resources in the internet.

my question is how to determine if the wearable device is 1.0 or 2.0. i made use of productFlavors based on this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) as follows:

```
android {
// Allows you to reference product flavors in your
// phone module's build.gradle file
publishNonDefault true
...
defaultConfig
{
   // This is the minSdkVersion of the Wear 1.x embedded app
   minSdkVersion 23
   ...
}
buildTypes {...}
productFlavors {
    wear1 {
      // Use the defaultConfig value
    }
    wear2 {
        minSdkVersion 25
    }
}
}
```

As i recalled, wear 1.0 usually collect data from phone and wear 2.0 has ability to access data via the internet. Please correct me if i am wrong.

So if the wearable is 1.0, it uses Wearable.API and sync with the phone. Otherwise, the wearable sync with cloud.

I had a look on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986474/how-to-programatically-detect-if-an-app-supports-android-wear) which seems useful but i do not quite understand.

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
```

Should i set a different packagename(or applicationId) for wear2 so that i can use this method? 
is there any drawback when i put standalone version on play store? i suppose i have to create a new project in this way.

Please can anyone advise the best way to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to distribute and maintain two separate APKs, then the build flavor is probably a reasonable way to go. But I would suggest that this won't be a good experience for either you or your users; it's more work for you, and it'll be confusing for them (*which version do I install? why doesn't this app work after I my watch upgraded to Wear 2.0?* and so on).

My suggestion would be to put it all in one APK, and simply choose which sync technique to use at run time:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {
    // Wear 1.x
} else {
    // Wear 2+
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. your way is straight forward to distinguish 1.0 and 2.0 in one code. hopefully, this way would work on some of the watches which can be from 1.0 to 2.0 recently.

Comment: This technique will work on all Wear devices, regardless.